# Page is empty after adding OnRowDataBound to a GridView

Tags: vb.net, gridview, webforms

I added a handler to OnRowDataBound event of my GridView, and after that the whole page is empty, as well as its page source. The same happens even if the handler method is empty. What is wrong?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="itemGridView" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    DataKeyNames="ItemID" 
    OnRowDataBound="itemGridView_RowDataBound"
    CssClass="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive" 
    BorderStyle="None"
    GridLines="None"
    AllowPaging="True">

 Private Sub itemGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aspx is a child of the codebehind page. So if you add event-handlers declaratively the handler method must be at least `Protected`.

```
Protected Sub itemGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

End Sub
```

Another option was to add the handler in the codebehind, either with `Handles` or with `AddHandler`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not expect it to work, as all other event handlers there are private... But it did work.

Comment: @DavidShochet: if the other handlers are private then they use `Handles`(at the method) or `AddHandler`(somewhere else).

Comment: Yes, they do. Is it the same, or I should also make it private with Handles?

Comment: @DavidShochet: that depends on what you want. If you want to add the handler on the aspx with `OnRowDataBound="itemGridView_RowDataBound"` then it has to be `Protected` or `Public`. Otherwise it's not accessible from there.